# Proof that the function $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)+3\cos(3x)$ has no period

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry

Proof that $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)+3\cos(3x)$ has no period. I've been trying to proof that assuming that there's a period $T$ but I haven't managed to come up with a controversy yet.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Hint: Convert this to a sum of two sines, then use the sum to product formula to convert it into something of the form $\cos(A)\cos(B)$.  Then, use the fact that the period of $\cos(A)\cos(B)$, if it exists, must be $n\alpha\beta$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the periods of $\cos(A)$ and $\cos(B)$ respectively

Comment: Try proving $\sin(ax)+\sin(bx)$ has no period if and only if $a/b$ is irrational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say there is a period $T$. Then $$\sin(\pi x)+3\cos(3x)=\sin(\pi(x+T))+3\cos(3(x+T))$$

Differentiating twice, we get $$\pi^2\sin(\pi x)+27\cos(3x)=\pi^2\sin(\pi(x+T))+27\cos(3(x+T))$$

Subtracting this from the $9$ times the original equation gives us $$\sin(\pi x)=\sin(\pi( x+T))\ \ \ \ \ (\star)$$

Putting this back into the original equation tells us that $$\cos(3x)=\cos(3x+3T)\Rightarrow 3T=2n\pi\Rightarrow T=\frac23n\pi$$

for some $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Now $(\star)$ also tells us that $$\sin x=\sin(x+\pi T)\Rightarrow \pi T=2k\pi\Rightarrow T=2k$$

for some $\mathbb Z$.

But then $$\frac23n\pi=2k\Rightarrow \pi=\frac{3k}{n}\in\mathbb Q$$ a contradiction. Thus the given function has no period.

---

A similar method shows that this holds for more general type of functions. I would leave it as an exercise to show that if $A,B\ne 0$ and $\frac{a}{b}\not\in\mathbb Q$, then $A\sin(ax)+B\cos(bx)$ has no period.

Answer (score 0):

There is another quiet simple method for this kind of problems about proving the period of a function doesn't exist.

Note that every function $f(x)$ can be written as the sum of an even function and an odd function (also is the unique form):$f(x)=(f(x)+f(-x))/2+(f(x)-f(-x))/2$. And in this problem the odd function is the sin and the even function is cos.Also if $f$ has period $T$,then both the odd function and the even function have the same period $T$,which is a contradiction.